# Specify cultures supported by application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, localization

Is there any way I can restrict my web application to certain cultures? So that .Net determines culture automatically, but the choice is restricted to these cultures.

For example, I would like to support only 'en-us' and 'it', so all other 'en' language clients will automatically be assigned 'en-us' culture.

UPDATE. I know how to set the thread culture, and I know how to determine the clients culture and then set the culture based on the clients 'base' culture (like set 'en' for all clients with 'en-xx' culture. I just want to do it properly.

Basically, I want to know how to limit the scope of cultures that is used to determine the culture when using culture="auto".

Comment: Are you talking about cultures regarding resource/language files, or do you want some logic with redirect to pages with the specified culture?

Comment: Resource/language files. I want to set CurrentThread culture without going through the list of available cultures. AFAIK, it's set automatically based on "accepted language" of the client, so I want asp.net to limit its choice to my specified 2 cultures.

Comment: You want ASP.NET to select a scope of cultures based on client info, not just one culture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set EN culture as a default one providing locales for more specific ones, like en-uk, en-us, etc. only if needed.

That won't help for other cases of subcultures. But is there a need for these cases?

**Update**.

I also found full resource fallback sequence [here](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwdbResourceProvider/introtolocalization.aspx) at Rick Strahl's blog (look for *Resource Fallback* header:

> The full sequence for resource lookups
> is:
>
> 1. Specific locale lookup (en-US)
> 2. Generic Language lookup (en)
> 3. Invariant

So not only you can provide default resource, you can specify default resource for generic language.

Comment: If that's the case I don't even have to worry about anything. Awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

you can get the ip of the client and use a web service to check his country 
then the country will return from this webservice so if his language is en you can assign him to english culture of your application

Comment: I already know the culture from the "accepted languages" string, but I don't want to go through 10 variations of English, since asp.net can just assign 'en' to all clients automatically.